# Getting the cell reference for a cell that's found by looping through an array?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I'm building a macro that needs to find a row based on the value in one column, then find the start of the data in that row, then cut that information and paste it onto a different sheet. I'm falling at the first hurdle because although I can get my array to loop through the column and find instances of the value, I can't seem to then get the cell reference of the value.

I've tried using the Range.Address function but that gets me a runtime error 424 Object required error. I'm not sure how to get the address. The code has found the value in the array, so it must know where that value is stored. Here's what I have so far

```
Dim element As Variant
Dim checker As Boolean
Dim elementAddr As String

MyArray = Range("S2:S10").Value2

For Each element In MyArray
    If element = "Completed." Then
    elementAddr = element.Address
    Worksheets("Test").Range("A1").Value = elementAddr
    Exit For
    End If
Next element

End Sub
```

So other than the error when trying to get the reference, the array loop works perfectly. Once the loop has found a cell in the array that says "Completed.", how can I then grab the reference of that cell as a string?

Comment: Only a `Range` object has an address property. Though to be honest I'd use `Application.Match` here instead of looping. Or you could use `Range.Find` - and then test the `.Address` of the result.

Comment: A good read: [Arrays and Ranges in VBA](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx)

Comment: I've managed to do this a different way, by copying the entire row using an incremented row number. It's less elegant but suitable for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

As BigBen notes you can use `Match()`:

```
Dim m

With Range("S2:S10")
    m = Application.Match("Completed.",.cells, 0)
    If Not IsError(m) Then Range("A1").value = .Cells(m).Address 
End With
```

or `Find()`:

```
Dim f As Range

Set f = Range("S2:S10").Find("Completed.", lookat:=xlWhole)
If Not f Is Nothing Then Range("A1").value = f.Address
```

Comment: This looks like the neatest solution but I'm struggling to understand the construct of it. Like the 'If Not F Is Nothing', does that mean if the values in the range are not blank?

Comment: @Tom no,  that just checks if the `Find` is successful.

Comment: Object-type variables are `Nothing` if they're not set to some object - `Find()` returns `Nothing` if it doesn't make a match to a cell in the search range.